# JavaFX how to show read-only text?

Tags: javafx

I want to show some text in my program and I tried with `TextArea`. However, the text shown is changeable. How can I make the text read only?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Maybe just a [text](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) would serve the purpose.

Or if you want to show the text in a text field, then:

```
tf.setDisable(true)
```

Comment: If you don't like the "disabled" look, `tf.setStyle("-fx-opacity: 1;");` will fix that.

Comment: @Aspirant Is there a way to make text uneditable and the pane unclickable but preserve the ability to scroll?

Comment: `@Aspirant Is there a way to make text uneditable and the pane unclickable but preserve the ability to scroll?`
@JacksonH, I would request you to create a new question for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 65):

I did it like this:

```
@FXML
private TextArea myText;
```

and then added the following code to `initialise()`:

```
myText.setEditable(false);
```

Answer (score 35):

I needed read-only text fields, but setting the **disabled** property used styling which was not correct in context (in my scenario, the text field was an input to a search function where a value could be fixed in some cases - disabling the text field implied that it was not part of the search, rather than the value was fixed).

In the end I landed up using:

```
txtInput.setEditable(false);
txtInput.setMouseTransparent(true);
txtInput.setFocusTraversable(false);
```

This results in a normal looking text field that is non-reactive to the user.

Comment: This answer is the best here, because it shows us how to do the "mouse transparent" and "focus (not) traversable" parts.  Even if we don't want to use these two lines, it's nice to know how to do these things.

Answer (score 14):

In FXML, add editable="false" to your TextField tag.
Or uncheck the "Editable" checkbox in Scene Builder.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

I would say just use a [`Label`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Label.html).

Comment: I dislike the use of a label in a case where you want to show a lot of text. For Example: You don't have a line cursor, which limits your ability to use the keyboard for traversing the text. I think labels are better used as short single word (maybe 2 - 3 words) displays. But OP didn't specify what he wants to display, so I you may probably be right.

Answer (score 4):

```
<TextField fx:id="input" disable="true"/>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Thx

Comment: @bub what is here to explain? You are disabling `TextField` via fxml file. You can reference to it from controller class by declaring `@FXML TextField input`.

Comment: A **good answer** will always have an **explanation** of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO. That  is here to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following statement in order to make text-area object non-editable with auto scrollbar:

`textAreaObjectName.setEditable(false);`

Hint: After setting the text to that respective textarea object using `textAreaObjectName.setText()` method.

Comment: please format the code as .. code (vs. bolding it)

Comment: @kleopatra yeah I'll update the solution code in appropriate format. Thanks for mentioning..